# SQL: Queries to Perform Statistical Calculations

Tags: sql, database

I have a data table that has the following columns: id (string), date (date), alert (0 or 1).

Some sample data:

```
case001     2011-06-18 8:27:00     0
case002     2011-06-18 16:30:00    1
case003     2011-06-19 7:24:00     0
...
case150     2011-10-23 22:05:00    1
case151     2011-10-24 11:45:00    1
case152     2011-10-24 16:55:00    0
case153     2011-10-24 20:13:00    0
...
```

I want to be able to write a few SQL queries to compute the number of alerts per day (where 1 represents an alert, 0 represents no alert) and also the number of alerts per id per day.

Any ideas?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Date functions tend to vary by implementation.

Comment: @Ed Harper: Sorry I omitted this: I'm using a MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which DB you are using.

In Oracle you can use `trunc` function to truncate to a day (or month, etc)

```
SELECT TRUNC(date, 'dd'), SUM(alert)
FROM alerts
GROUP BY TRUNC(date, 'dd')
```

In MySQL you should use

```
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```